# issue with the code, not able to use map array for print the view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code.

```
class Squence extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.data = []
    }
    render() { 
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            this.data.push(i);
        }
        return ( 
                <View>
                {this.data.map((item) => {
                    <View key={item} style={{height: 20, width: 20, backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft: 3, marginTop: 3}}><Text>{item}</Text></View>
                })}
                </View>
         );
    }
}
export default Squence;
```

I think my code is not wrong, but it doesn't work!
What's the reason?
I used the map method with the wrong?

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by "doesn't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `map`. Use `()` instead of `{}` or type `return` explicitly. Here are some examples:

```
this.data.map(item => <View>...</View>);

this.data.map(item => (
    <View>...</View>
));

this.data.map(item => {
    return <View>...</View>;
});
```

Comment: But ,my map function is in return part?

Comment: Your `map` still has to `return`.

Comment: @JohnMiller No, it isn't; you have curly-braces `{}` around the arrow function body which means you need an explicit return.

Comment: Okay!.Thank you.

Comment: yes.I solve the problem.I had been in some contradiction